# Google Script code for ordering rows by mouse click

Tags: google-sheets

I need a google script that will work for reorder rows by mouse click in header rows. It will be use to reorder rows in ascending and descending order simultaneously.

Comment: I need complete code that can be used in script editor of Google sheet.. In this code so that I can order rows in mouse click. Thanks

Comment: As I need to make the google sheet link with others who do not have sufficient knowledge on reorder bu filter option. More over this will also be used by elderly people so that they can reorder rows just by mouse click. I will be grateful if a button that can be place in the rows to reorder just clicking that button. Please give me complete code for that. Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow for people to ask for help with problems with their existing code, not a code writing service. We are happy to help if you can show something for yourself otherwise you might want to hire a freelancer.

Comment: I have code that is ok for excel. Is it ok to use same for google script-please

Answer (score 0):

There is no onClick() function in Google App Script. There is only onEdit(). There are ways around this, such as having a little box next to the header, and depending on what you put in there it will reorder. As Robin already mentioned though, why isn't the built in sorting enough?

Comment: Please provide me the code for putting box to the header.Thanks

Comment: As Robin already mentioned, Stack Overflow is for helping people with existing code. If you want someone to write it for you, you should probably look into hiring. If you actually take the time to try, then i'd be happy to help you.

Comment: I have just completed by using a menu and I put the function on that menu for order as I need. I think some hints will be better to make people more interested instead of discourage people like telling them hiring free lancers. Thanks. I can put here complete process if some one wants.

Comment: @kabirbaf Post your existing code next time and tell everyone what you've done to try and figure it out. Then people will be happy to help. Its not about discouraging people, it's about filtering out the lazy ones. I'm glad you figured it out, and you should absolutely post your answer to help future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Order_Parents')
    .addItem('Natural_Order__Parents', 'Natural_Order__Parents')
   .
     ui.createMenu('Order_Map_URL')

      .addItem('Natural_Order_Map_URL', 'Natural_Order_Map_URL')     
               .addToUi();
   }
```